# Ransack: Order by year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, ransack

I am working with ransack and I need to sort by the year (just year, not the whole date) of creation. So I have this in the controller:

```
@q = Book.search(params[:q])
@q.sorts = 'book_year' if q.sorts.blank?
@books = @q.result(distinct: true)
           .select('books.*, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM books.created_at) as book_year')
           .page(params[:page])
```

But it doesn't work. The order is not added to the sql query.

Do you know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Sort order will remove when you execute `select` query on ransack result, as it will execute the query to the database to fetch the records. to apply sort on the result you have to add order clause after the select clause.

```
@q = Book.search(params[:q])
@q.sorts = 'book_year' if q.sorts.blank?
@books = @q.result(distinct: true)
           .select('books.*, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM books.created_at) as book_year')
           .order('book_year')
           .page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need, given I have multiple sort links and I don't want to force the sort to be "book_year" always